# Error on microservices using common libraries ,not finding pom and jar of shared library

Tags: java, maven, repository, microservices, pom.xml

i'm building this app composed of several microservices , using common and reusable classes all shared in a package of name commons , which at the same time is imported on each and every microservice needed of using whatever the cladsses common shares.
For some reason one of the microservices(microproducts)was needed of generating a new jar , but on the process i got warning of not finding first the common library in its pom and second , throws me an error , all this when im deploying on docker images each and every of the micro's.

my work sapce structure with all the components including common and all else microservices would be like this :
[image]

Lets say my common library would be designed like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>commons</name>
    <description>Demo project for commons</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--PARA EL MANEJO DE JPA-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--        SPRING REST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!--INACTIVANDOSE EL PLUGIN AL SER ESTO SOLO UNA LIBRERIA -->
    <build>
       
    </build>

</project>
```

Being its main class disabled due to ist function of shareable resource:

```
package com.commons;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;


@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class CommonsApplication {
}
```

Then on one of my microservices(microproducts) i do first import that common library on its pom and second in its main class i scan all components , entities, base packages  the class needed coming from common in order to work

MICROPRODUCTS POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.microproducts</groupId>
    <artifactId>microproducts</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>microproducts</name>
    <description>Demo project for microproducts</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR9</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--LIBRERIA COMUN DE COMMONS CREADA-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        SWAGGER 2-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        SWAGGER UI-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        JPA-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--        SPRING REST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--        SPRING WEB-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--        EUREKA CLIENT-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
                </dependency>

       <!--        SLEUTH TRACE CONEXION-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
                </dependency>

        <!--        ZIPKIN-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
                </dependency>

        <!-- DEPENDENCIA CONNECTORA DE RABBIT MQ  PARA EL MANEJO DE RESPUESTAS Y LOGS SOBRE
        TRAZAS EN ZIPKING SERVER-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--DEVTOOLS-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

      
        <!--        CONNEXION A MYSQL-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--        TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

As you can see the common library is imported as first

then the main class got designed in this way:

```
package com.microproducts;

import com.microproducts.repositories.ImgSubTypeRepository;
import com.microproducts.repositories.ProductRepository;
import com.microproducts.repositories.RenterRepository;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.commons.dtos","com.commons.exceptions","com.commons.responses","com.commons.repositories","com.commons.responses"})
@EntityScan("com.commons.entities")
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {ProductRepository.class, RenterRepository.class, ImgSubTypeRepository.class})
public class MicroproductsApplication  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroproductsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Any idea about why this behave of not letting me to build a jar cause of not "finding" my common jar previously imported?
[image]

Comment: You are using a spring boot application as dependency which will not work cause the result of a spring boot application is not intended for reuse as a usual lib jar ... so extract the common code into a separate component with spring boot `@SpringBootApplication`...

Comment: is in that way  common is a separate component o the rest of microservices

Answer (score 0):

As khbmarbaise said:

If you use `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent, the module/project cannot be used as dependency.

Comment: explain yourself  J fabian please

Comment: Are you suggesting i should delete the parent tag represented inthe commons pom in order to make this process to work?

Comment: How come?...cause before trying to deploy this process on docker images , i have being in development mode doing tests , creating deleting  jars , and this problem never happened?

Comment: If you use `spring-boot-starter-parent`, the classes will not be put to the usual directory inside the JAR, but to a different one. This means that other JARs cannot find them. Inside IDEs like Eclipse or IntelliJ, this may not be noticed because the magic of the IDEs which often resolve classes in a different way.

Answer (score -1):

well guess deleting the  .m2 repository, rebuilding all proyects including the common one would do the work